# breadcrumb markup - home and current page?

Tags: html, markup, breadcrumbs, rich-snippets

Are you supposed to markup the home and current page for the breadcrumb?  I am using data-vocabulary only because schema.org doesn't allow titles or urls to be marked up - only a line of text without dividers unless added manually.

Here is an example of what I have now.  Notice that I marked up both the home and current page - is this correct or should one or both not be marked up?

```
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="home" itemprop="url" href="/"><span itemprop="title"><img alt="Home" height="30" src="/images/trans.gif" width="16"></span></a></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="/services/"><span itemprop="title">Services</a></span></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="/service/widget/"><span itemprop="title">Widget</a></span></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="/service/widget/features.htm"><span itemprop="title">Features</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Nobody knows the answer to this one?

Comment: You have errors in your HTML - the first <li> is ok, but the next 2 have closing </span> and </a> tags in wrong order.

Comment: Your example seems fine, see [Google Webmaster Tools](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417). But I think it will only work with text not images.

Comment: All I want to know is if you are supposed to markup your home (www.test.com) for example. Then if you are supposed to markup your current page... say I am at www.test.com/here.htm do I list that as my last link in the breadcrumb?

Comment: Google's testing tool is currently giving an error if a breadcrumb item doesn't have a URL specified. Well the last breadcrumb, if it is the current page, generally won't have a URL like a link. So now it seems like Google doesn’t want the current page to actually be marked up as a breadcrumb currently. But things aren't finalized - "Note: This article describes an older format. Schema.org markup for breadcrumbs is being finalized and will be preferred when ready." (Last updated February 12, 2015) https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs 
So I guess we'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the following that appears to work, I think you just had a couple of the ending `</span></a>` tags the wrong way around.

```
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="home" itemprop="url" href="/"><span itemprop="title"><img alt="Home" height="30" src="/images/trans.gif" width="16"></span></a></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="/services/"><span itemprop="title">Services</span></a></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="/service/widget/"><span itemprop="title">Widget</span></a></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="/service/widget/features.htm"><span itemprop="title">Features</span></a></li>
```

You have probably already read it but you can read more on Breadcrumbs here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417 the "Microdata" link has a good example.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I was asking at all.  As my OP mentioned I need to know if you are supposed to mark up the home and/or current page you are on.  This is what I need to know and nothing specifies if you do or not.